# On Steam, how can I see who a friend is on Facebook after they've been linked?

Tags: steam, facebook

I found a number of my steam friends via the facebook  integration. It's an easy process, you go to a page in steam, it shows you who on facebook isn't yet in your friends list, and then you check boxes to add them to your steam friends.

This is all well and good, but because the namespaces are completely different, there's no way to know what friend ladayada71272 on steam would be on Facebook. And I absolutely cannot find a way to get that information.

Normally I wouldn't care, but someone gifted me a game and used my name, so they're obviously someone I know on Facebook but I have no way to thank them and know who they are in the process.

Is the Steam interface broken or is it me?

Comment: Have you ever simply just tried to message them on Steam and ask them who they are/thank them via chat? I know that's not really answering your question, but I feel like that's the easiest way.

Comment: Just a quick update: you can now add Nicknames to friends, so that even if they change their tag, you can easily see at a glance whom they are.

Comment: I found this question looking for the opposite. I have a mate on facebook and I want to add him on steam; where is the 'page' you mentioned in the second sentence?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually, there is a way. In your friends list, click the drop-down arrow and there will be a "View Facebook Page" link if they've linked their accounts.

[image]

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but if they use a funny alias in addition to their funny steam account name, then this is useless. Which isn't to say this is an incorrect answer, because it might be correct. One might say if they are using a funny alias then who cares, and maybe I should just thank them by their alias. I'd just like to know who actually sent this so when I see them in person I might reference.

Comment: @InsidiousForce: Yeah, there's no way to do it for sure though, sadly.

Comment: I'll leave this for a while to determine if anyone out there knows some brilliant way to get this, and if that doesn't happen in a few days or so I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: @InsidiousForce: Thomas McDonald actually mentioned a way in chat. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Too bad you can't do this in the browser. I actually browse steam quite a bit in firefox.

Comment: Does NOT work for me in steam client in november 2016...