# What kinds of things happen when I link Steam and Facebook?

Tags: steam, facebook

I really hate Facebook apps. I've probably blocked a few hundred or so. Mostly the reasons are twofold:

1. I don't want to spam my friends with random crap that I'm doing
2. I find that most gaming is more interesting to me in a more rich environment (consoles, or a DirectX experience), and none of the games are really appealing when I've got other games to play.

So, what will happen if I merge Steam and Facebook?

- Will it automagically post to facebook any time I get a steam achievement?
- Will it post to facebook at other times?
- Do I have control over that? Can I hold back posts to facebook?
- What kind of information is available to my friends on each service?

Comment: I would suggest putting together a dummy Facebook account if you're doing this for the achievement.  I personally have no desire to link Facebook and Steam, regardless of how many "25% off a game that is currently 75% off" coupons I'm offered.

Comment: @agent86 that's exactly my hesitation.

Comment: @McKay You could also just use your Facebook account, decline the wall post, and unlink it immediately and delete the Steam app. That's enough for the objective.

Comment: @lunboks But maybe I do want the connection to steam. I'm just wary. It is a good idea though.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This [Steam Facebook FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20160320040848/https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9942-YUOM-5443) seems to answer most of your questions.

When you link your Facebook account to Steam, Steam tries to find if any of your Facebook friends are also on Steam, and suggests that you add them. You also get the option to invite your Facebook friends to link accounts as well, via a wall post, but that can simply be declined.

> [image: Facebook post - Link Steam and Facebook Profiles]

Your Steam friend limit is also increased by 50.

The [support article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160320040848/https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9942-YUOM-5443) explicitly states that nothing will be posted to your wall automatically:

> **Are you going to post status messages to my wall?**
>   Steam will not post anything to your Facebook wall without your permission.

Comment: KB link has died.  Link rot, still the scourge of the Internet.

Answer (score 3):

Linking Steam to Facebook will not post anything to your wall. The only thing it enables you to do is find your Facebook friends through Steam's friend system.

> Now it is easier than ever to find your friends on Steam. Just link your Facebook profile with Steam and see your friends who have done the same. Don't worry, we won't post anything to your Facebook wall without your approval.

Source: http://store.steampowered.com/news/5644/

Comment: [Also, it lets your steam friends find your Facebook page.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43405/on-steam-how-can-i-see-who-a-friend-is-on-facebook-after-theyve-been-linked)